# Sort list of strings numerically and filter duplicates?

Tags: python, list, sorting, duplicates

Given a list of strings in the following format:

```
[
    "464782,-100,4,3,1,100,0,0"
    "465042,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "465825,-250.000000000001,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "466868,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "467390,-200.000000000001,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "469999,-100,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "470260,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "474173,-100,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "474434,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "481477,-100,4,3,1,100,0,1",
    "531564,259.011439671919,4,3,1,60,1,0",
    "24369,-333.333333333335,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "21082,410.958904109589,4,3,1,60,1,0",
    "21082,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "22725,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "23547,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "24369,-333.333333333335,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "27657,-200.000000000001,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "29301,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "30123,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "30945,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "32588,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "34232,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "35876,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "36698,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "37520,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "42451,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "43273,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
]
```

How can I sort the list based on the first number in each line with python?
And then, once sorted, remove all duplicates, if any are there?

The sorting criteria for the list is the number before the first comma in each line, which is always an integer.

I tried using list.sort() , however, this sorts the items in lexical order, not numerically.

Comment: Could put it into a pandas df as separate columns then sort and remove dups?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? That data looks like CSV, no?

Comment: @AMC Its not a CSV file (even tho it appears to have a similar structure), it is just a list of strings.
I updated the original post to make the example more clear.

Comment: @Kyu96 Where do the strings come from? Is the data all numeric, can we split on commas?

Comment: @AMC The origin of the data should not be relevant. Rather the idea is to treat the data as something of which origin I have no control over.

Comment: @Kyu96 _The origin of the data should not be relevant._ If you were reading this from a file, then I would suggest that you use a proper CSV library, that’s all. _Rather the idea is to treat the data as something of which origin I have no control over._ 

Comment: I think Pandas is probably your best bet for this.

Comment: Can't you just `sorted(set(yourlist))`? There's no need to `split()` or anything magical. `set()` will remove the duplicates and then `sorted()` will do the right thing.

Comment: what's the criteria for dupes? just the first item in each row, or the whole row itself

Comment: @accdias See the last sentence in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a dictionary for this. The key will be number before the first comma and the value the entire string. Duplicates will be eliminated, but only the last occurrence of a particular number's string is stored.

```
l = ['464782,-100,4,3,1,100,0,0',
'465042,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0',
'465825,-250.000000000001,4,3,1,100,0,0',
'466868,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0',
'467390,-200.000000000001,4,3,1,100,0,0',
...]

d = {int(s.split(',')[0]) : s for s in l}
result = [d[key] for key in sorted(d.keys())]
```

Comment: this will remove dupes for the sort key not the rest of the data. is that the criteria?

Comment: @aws_apprentice Yes, that is fine. Dupe checking can be done based on the sort key.

Answer (score 1):

I would try one of these two methods:

```py
def sort_list(lis):
    nums = [int(num) if isdigit(num) else float(num) for num in lis]

    nums = list(set(nums))
    nums.sort()

    return [str(i) for i in nums]  # I assumed you wanted them to be strings.
```

The first will raise a `TypeError` if all items in `lis` are not `ints`, `floats`, or string representations of a number. The second method doesn't have that problem, but it's a bit wonkier.

```py
def sort_list(lis):
    ints = [int(num) for num in lis if num.isdigit()]
    floats = [float(num) for num in lis if not num.isdigit()]

    nums = ints.copy()
    nums.extend(floats)
    nums = list(set(nums))
    nums.sort()

    return [str(i) for i in nums]  # I assumed you wanted them to be strings.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The sorting criteria is the value before the first comma, which is always an integer.

Comment: In what way does the first number affect the process? I also see that as of your latest edit, my code wouldn't help. You have a list of strings, which are list-like, but aren't lists themselves. My function was made with the intention of taking a list of string numbers. I'll make another edit to handle it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

First we need to remove the duplicates inside the list using set()

```
removed_duplicates_list = list(set(listr))
```

Then we convert the list of strings in to a list of tuples

```
list_of_tuples = [tuple(i.split(",")) for i in removed_duplicates_list]
```

Then we sort it using the sort()

```
list_of_tuples.sort()
```

The complete code sample below:

```
listr = [
    "464782,-100,4,3,1,100,0,0"
    "465042,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "465825,-250.000000000001,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "466868,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "467390,-200.000000000001,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "469999,-100,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "470260,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "474173,-100,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "474434,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "481477,-100,4,3,1,100,0,1",
    "531564,259.011439671919,4,3,1,60,1,0",
    "24369,-333.333333333335,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "21082,410.958904109589,4,3,1,60,1,0",
    "21082,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "22725,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "23547,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "24369,-333.333333333335,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "27657,-200.000000000001,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "29301,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "30123,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "30945,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "32588,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "34232,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "35876,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "36698,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "37520,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "42451,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0",
    "43273,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0",
]

removed_duplicates_list = list(set(listr))
list_of_tuples = [tuple(i.split(",")) for i in removed_duplicates_list]
list_of_tuples.sort()
print(list_of_tuples) # the output is a list of tuples
```

OUTPUT:

```
    [('21082', '-250', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('21082', '410.958904109589', '4', '3', '1', '60', '1', '0'),
    ('22725', '-142.857142857143', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('23547', '-166.666666666667', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('24369', '-333.333333333335', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('27657', '-200.000000000001', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('29301', '-142.857142857143', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('30123', '-166.666666666667', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('30945', '-250', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('32588', '-166.666666666667', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('34232', '-250', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('35876', '-142.857142857143', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('36698', '-166.666666666667', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('37520', '-250', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('42451', '-142.857142857143', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('43273', '-166.666666666667', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),  
    ('464782','-100','4','3','1','100','0'),
    ('465042','-166.666666666667','4','3','1','100','0','0'),
    ('465825', '-250.000000000001', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('466868', '-166.666666666667', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('467390', '-200.000000000001', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('469999', '-100', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('470260', '-166.666666666667', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('474173', '-100', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('474434', '-166.666666666667', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '0'),
    ('481477', '-100', '4', '3', '1', '100', '0', '1'),
    ('531564', '259.011439671919', '4', '3', '1', '60', '1', '0')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help to.
I place all your list elements in a separate file named **lista.txt**
In this example I will get your list from file... I like to be more organizated and to have separate files you can do in on python as well, but the idea is you need to get all elements from list one by one (**while** function or **for** function) and to add them to a temporary list by checking if the new items already exist, if is exist pass and then you can sample use **.sort()** because will do the trick and with numbers.

```
# Global variables
file = "lista.txt"
tempList = []

# Logic get items from file
def GetListFromFile(fileName):
    # Local variables
    showDoneMsg = True

    # Try to run this code
    try:
        # Open file and try to read it
        with open(fileName, mode="r") as f:
            # Define line
            line = f.readline()
            # For every line in file
            while line:
                # Get out all end white space (\n, \r)
                item = line.rstrip()

                # Check if this item is not allready in the list
                if item not in tempList:
                    # Append item to a temporar list
                    tempList.append(item)
                # Show me if a itmes allready exist
                else:
                    print("Dublicate >>", item)

                # Go to new line
                line = f.readline()
        # This is optional because is callet automatical
        # but I like to be shore
        f.close()

    # Execptions
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("ERROR >> File do not exist!")
        showDoneMsg = False

    # Sort the list
    tempList.sort()
    # Show me when is done if file exist
    if showDoneMsg == True:
        print("\n>>> DONE <<<\n")

# Logic show list items
def ShowListItems(thisList):
    if len(thisList) == 0:
        print("Temporary list is empty...")
    else:
        print("This is new items list:")
        for i in thisList:
            print(i)

# Execute function
GetListFromFile(file)
# Testing if items was sorted
ShowListItems(tempList)
```

Out put:

```
========================= RESTART: D:\Python\StackOverflow\help.py =========================
Dublicate >> 43273,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0

>>> DONE <<<

21082,-250,4,3,1,100,0,0
21082,410.958904109589,4,3,1,60,1,0
22725,-142.857142857143,4,3,1,100,0,0
...
474434,-166.666666666667,4,3,1,100,0,0
481477,-100,4,3,1,100,0,1
531564,259.011439671919,4,3,1,60,1,0
>>>
```

Comment: Why the try-finally? Why aren't you following PEP 8?

Comment: try to check some error just in case and finnaly because something need to be after try. If I was get an error then I was add except but I was not gen any error on sample code... I do not know what mean PEP 8

Comment: _try to check some error just in case_ There's no except statement though? _finnaly because something need to be after try._ The try which as we just saw is unnecessary? I'm confused. _If I was get an error then I was add except but I was not gen any error on sample code_ Then what's the point?

Comment: @ASI, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is Python's guideline for code formatting. But don't take that guy's comment too seriously. He's just kind of a troll here, that rarely helps anyone with a good answer.

Comment: @accdias  thanks, I think you are right... AMC I updated the code, noew shod be more logical for you as well